# FabricJS: Cannot clone objects or images as they are undefined

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am new to FabricJS and have been playing around with it quite a bit. I am trying to build onto an onto an open source image editor. Currently, this code allows me to clone objects such as shapes, but i cannot clone groups of objects at a time and I also cannot clone images or groups of images. The error I get from cloning a group of objects or any images is:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Or the error for cloning images in this case would be:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Here is my code for cloning objects:

```
function clone() {
var object = null;
   if (canvas.getActiveGroup()) {
     var objects = canvas.getActiveGroup().objects;

     canvas.deactivateAll();

     var cloned = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        object = objects[i].clone();

        object.set("top", object.top + 20);
        object.set("left", object.left + 20);
        canvas.add(object);
        cloned.push(object);
     }

     selectAll(cloned);
   } else if (canvas.getActiveObject()) {
     object = canvas.getActiveObject().clone();
     object.set("top", object.top + 20);
     object.set("left", object.left + 20);
     canvas.add(object);

     canvas.deactivateAll();
     canvas.setActiveObject(object);
    }

    canvas.renderAll();

    canvas.trigger("object:statechange");
}
```

And here is the code that I use to import images:

```
document.getElementById('imgLoader').onchange = function handleImage(e) {
var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (event){
  var imgObj = new Image();
  imgObj.src = event.target.result;
  imgObj.onload = function () {
    var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
    image.set({
          angle: 0,
          padding: 10,
          cornersize:10,
          height:110,
          width:110,
    });
    canvas.centerObject(image);
    canvas.add(image);
    canvas.renderAll();
  };
};
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
};
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read here:

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html

[image]

Clone is an async function.
It does not return anything.

```
function clone() {
var object = canvas.getActiveGroup();
   if (object) {
     object.clone(function(clone) {
       clone.set("top", object.top + 20);
       clone.set("left", object.left + 20);
       canvas.deactivateAll();
       clone.getObjects().forEach(function(obj){
         canvas.add(obj);
       });
       clone.canvas = canvas;
       canvas.setActiveGroup(clone);
     });    
   }
var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
 if (object) {
       object = object.clone(function(cloned){
         cloned.set("top", object.top + 20);
         cloned.set("left", object.left + 20);
         canvas.add(cloned);
         canvas.deactivateAll();
         canvas.setActiveObject(object);
       });
     }
     canvas.renderAll();
     canvas.trigger("object:statechange");
    }
```